Restore .pbak File
i want to make sure that .pbak file is a valid backup. what steps to Restore a .pbak File?
If you provide more details about the backup that created the .pbak file, I can offer more specific for you.. im looking forware to help !!!

I have removed the unrelated  tag, since this isn't about the ISO/ANSI SQL language. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms you're using.
